# How to create Illustrations with thick outer strokes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, stroke, illustration

I have seen quite a lot of illustrations on Dribble which have thick strokes. For example this one.

### [image: Octopus]

I have a general idea, and can go about making some of my own designs like this.

[image: My Try at Illustrations with Thick Strokes[3]]

But I don't think that the way that I am approaching this design is correct. If someone could help me understand the proper technique to approach it would be very helpful. A tutorial or even speed art helps.

Comment: Possible Duplicates: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13476/removing-part-of-a-stroke-and-adding-a-gradient-to-a-stroke-in-illustrator-cs5 and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81438/add-thick-outline-to-existing-artwork-in-illustrator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add thick outline to existing artwork in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81438/add-thick-outline-to-existing-artwork-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I call that style *dribbble-esqqque*. It has no particular name. Just happens to be a trendy style. Words you could use to describe it, though:

- iconography
- fixed-width line art
- flat color
- flat shading

Your style is certainly a valid style, but the primary differences:

- you used multiple stroke widths (instead of one width)
- you use a lot more detail
- you aren't using any shading for depth effect

Answer (score 3):

Comparing your image and the original, a few differences are very clear:

- Use a thick stroke for large details, all the same thickness;
- shadow and light are done with solid color blocks;
- smaller details are done with color blocks as well;
- all stroke caps are round.

You should get a good grasp of light and shadow technique to give it proper volume, and for creating the vector shapes itself there are plenty of illustration tutorials around the web.